# Setting up facebook authentication schema with existing user schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, oauth

I want to integrate facebook into my app through OAuth but I already have an existing user schema set up. Here's my current schema:

```
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  first_name      :string(255)
#  last_name       :string(255)
#  email           :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime        not null
#  updated_at      :datetime        not null
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  remember_token  :string(255)
#  admin           :boolean         default(FALSE)
#
```

What would be the best way to add facebook auth using rails?

Comment: It depends on a couple of factors. Do you want to allow a user to login to the same account using 2 different facebook accounts? Are you thinking of adding other authentication methods in the future?

Comment: ideally i'd like them to be able to login using one email account and have the facebook account connected as well so i can extend the site using social graph.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: no. i'm not sure what the proper way of storing/regenerating access_tokens are alongside the uid from facebook

Answer (score 0):

There are still a couple of different ways for you to do this.

1. Use the email with which people login to facebook to establish a connection between their facebook account and your site account.
2. Add a new column to your users database (called uid, type string). When you use oauth, a hash of information about the user is returned, including that unique identifier. [Here's an example.](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash) You can then store this uid to later use as a way to login.

Regardless of these implementation choices, you'll want to use the [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) gem and the [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) gem (you need a different gem for every provider). See the project's wiki for more info. It's really easy to use. In your case, to get it working, all you have to do is add these 2 gems to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Then create a file to setup your strategies. The convention is naming it omniauth.rb:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET
end
```

To get an API Key and an API Secret you need to create a Facebook app to handle the oauth connection. So head on to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and create it. Then don't forget to edit these setting:

```
Settings>Basic>Website>Site URL:
  http://localhost:3000/ for development/testing
  your_website_callback_url for production
```